# Send User ID Variable With Paypal Subscribe - PhoneGap

Tags: android, paypal, cordova, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to tally a Paypal Subsciption to an app user (in Android).

Currently I'm using the generated Paypal subscribe button, that links out to the payment page.

How can I send the users ID and have it posted on success to a URL (where PHP will update the database etc) ?

Any ideas or suggestions appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847114/can-i-send-a-variable-to-paypal-and-have-it-post-it-back-to-me-when-payment-comp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a server, on first launch of your app, contact the server to generate an ID for your app, save that ID somewhere, and use that ID to generate your PayPal button.